# Have we invented a universally accepted name for image + text on it?

Tags: single-word-requests

These days in social networks we see a new medium emerging (which I think did not exist before, at least not in this scale):

Images with a relavent text on it.

Examples can be seen in this site:

http://FunnyAnd.com

I can't find a word to describe them. Do we have a word for this art/medium?

Comment: Without following your link the format you describe sounds like ["image macros"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_macro) (Wikipedia). They may attain the status of "memes" if sufficiently popular.

Answer (score 1):

## Image Macro

: a photographic image on which a humorous caption or catchphrase has been digitally superimposed.

---

### Meme

: an element of a culture or system of behavior that may be considered to be passed from one individual to another by nongenetic means, especially imitation.

- a humorous image, video, piece of text, etc. that is copied (often with slight variations) and spread rapidly by Internet users.

---

The correct term would be **image macro**. Every image macro is a meme, but not every meme is an image macro, if you get my gist.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I disagree on the **universally accepted** attribute of the term **image macro**. A simple search on Google images reveal that. If anything is globally accepted, it will be used everywhere, and if something is used all over the places a search engine like Google would notice it.

Comment: If that is not a universally accepted word, then there is none as of today.